# Sorting through a multidimensional associative array and changing only updated options

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have users filling out a form, and once it has been posted they are able to change their answers. I have it posted to options in wordpress.

I have this update attached to a button, and this is the code for it

```
    if(isset ($_POST['plugin-guide-info-update']) == 'Update') {
    $hidden_field_updated = esc_html ( $_POST['plugin-guide-info-form-updated']) ;

        if( $hidden_field_updated == 'Y' ) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($guide_info); $i++) {

                if (!empty( $_POST['wpt_guide_name_update_delete_' . $i]) ){

                    $guide_name = esc_html( $_POST['wpt_guide_name_update_delete_' . $i] );

                    $guide_description= esc_html( $_POST['wpt_guide_description_update_delete_' . $i] );

                    $guide_info = array ( 'guide_name' => $guide_name, 'guide_description' => $guide_description);

                    $options = array_replace($options[$i], $guide_info);

                    update_option( 'assist', $options);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I do this nothing happens, nothing is changed in options. What would I be missing?

[Update_option is a wordpress function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)

Var_dump does not output anything

I've tried a foreach loop, and I've thought about going over each key and value and seeing which is different compared to what's there and changing it, but that would change all of them to the new one because the change would be different to what's there...

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what `update_option()` does.  Also, what steps have you taken to debug this?  `var_dump()` is your friend...

Comment: @devlincarnate I've edited it

Comment: Does `var_dump($options)` return the results you expect, and if so, can you show us a sampling?

Comment: var_dump doesn't return the results I expect (or rather what I would like). It completely rewrites everything that I have in $options and only leaves the edited content. If I have 4 arrays inside $options and edit the 3rd one, it deletes everything and moves the edited content to the first place

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the `$guide_info` array while iterating over it.  That's a problem.  That problem cascades down to `$options` where you reference `$guide_info`, and then you also further the problem by modifying the `$options` array while relying on the index `$i`, which isn't going to be in the right place.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($guide_info); $i++) {
     //..other stuff
     $guide_info = array ( 'guide_name' => $guide_name, 'guide_description' => $guide_description);
     $options = array_replace($options[$i], $guide_info);
}
```

The solution is to stop modifying arrays you're iterating over.  And don't modify an array and then expect the index in your loop to be pointing at the right place on the next iteration.

One way to do this, in your case, is to use a different array for your modified result set, like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($guide_info); $i++) {
     //..other stuff
     $guide_info_new = array ( 'guide_name' => $guide_name, 'guide_description' => $guide_description);
     $options_new = array_replace($options[$i], $guide_info_new);
     update_option( 'assist', $options_new);
}
```

This will leave the original `$guide_info` and `$options` arrays intact, so your iteration loops as expected.

---

**Update**

If the intention with `$options` is to add to the array, then use `array_push()` instead of `array_replace()`.  And call update_option outside of your loop, since you are passing it an array.  In other words, build the array inside the loop and then pass it to the update_option function after the loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($guide_info); $i++) {
     //..other stuff
     $guide_info_new = array ( 'guide_name' => $guide_name, 'guide_description' => $guide_description);
     array_push($options, $guide_info_new);
}
update_option( 'assist', $options);
```

Comment: When I do that it only outputs the new edited array and deletes everything else still